# br_netfilter error when deploying docker containers to swarm on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, docker-swarm, ubuntu-20.04

I've been struggling to deploy my containers to Docker swarm on Ubuntu server 20.04.
I'm trying to use Docker swarm on a single VPS host for zero-downtime deployments.

Running containers with docker-compose everything works.

Now trying to deploy the same docker-compose file to docker swarm.

```
# docker swarm init
Swarm initialized: current node (wlshyv0s1n5c85mao8jt9wo5j) is now a manager.

To add a worker to this swarm, run the following command:
...

# docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml dash
Ignoring unsupported options: build

Creating network dash_default
Creating service dash_db
Creating service dash_nginx
...
```

After finishing the deploy command, with `docker ps` i see that there are no running containers.

Now checking with `docker ps -a` I see a lot of containers and all their statuses say "Created".

Next when i inspect one container, then it's state shows that:

```
"State": {
    "Status": "created",
    "Running": false,
    "Paused": false,
    "Restarting": false,
    "OOMKilled": false,
    "Dead": false,
    "Pid": 0,
    "ExitCode": 128,
    "Error": "error creating external connectivity network: cannot restrict inter-container communication: please ensure that br_netfilter kernel module is loaded",
    "StartedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
}
```

Checking for loaded modules:

```
# lsmod | grep br_netfilter
br_netfilter            4242  -2
bridge                  4242  -2 br_netfilter,ebtable_broute
```

After running `docker info` i saw 2 warnings:

```
# docker info
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  app: Docker App (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-beta3)
  buildx: Build with BuildKit (Docker Inc., v0.5.1-docker)

Server:
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 40
 Server Version: 20.10.5
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: active
  NodeID: ij25ein3xvcr8p5ky765ol8t0
  Is Manager: true
  ClusterID: mdb2r7vnngw62lg8uoj5ef55k
  Managers: 1
  Nodes: 1
  Default Address Pool: 10.0.0.0/8
  SubnetSize: 24
  Data Path Port: 4789
  Orchestration:
   Task History Retention Limit: 5
  Raft:
   Snapshot Interval: 10000
   Number of Old Snapshots to Retain: 0
   Heartbeat Tick: 1
   Election Tick: 10
  Dispatcher:
   Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
  CA Configuration:
   Expiry Duration: 3 months
   Force Rotate: 0
  Autolock Managers: false
  Root Rotation In Progress: false
  ...
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 05f951a3781f4f2c1911b05e61c160e9c30eaa8e
 runc version: 12644e614e25b05da6fd08a38ffa0cfe1903fdec
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 5.4.0
 Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 2
 Total Memory: 4GiB
 ...
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
```

Searching for a solution I found that I should call the `sysctl` command, but I still get an error.

```
# sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables=1
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-ip6tables: No such file or directory
```

Now searching solution for that I found the next command, but that does not work as well.

```
# modprobe br_netfilter
modprobe: FATAL: Module br_netfilter not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0
```

I don't know anymore what to do, to make swarm work.

Everything works on my Windows machine while using swarm mode.

Any suggestions on what should I do/check next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That problem was in the hosting provider.

Provider told us that other customers have tried to configure Docker Swarm on their VPS too, but no one has figured out how to get it to work.

The provider didn't allow any kernel modification or anything else on the lower level.

Now we are using another hosting provider and everything works fine.

Comment: I can confirm after trying Centos7, Centos8 and Ubuntu20,  A2Hosting does not seem to allow this.  Which provider are you using now ??

Comment: We are using our local hosting provider, which is not very popular internationally, but the trick is in that, that VPS container has to use KVM virtualization.

Comment: In the end I tried a Centos8 VPS on Digital Ocean, it worked fine first time.